# why i got this error "WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: front and back stencils settings do not match"

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

my code is below. error line is the last line.

```
  gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
  gl.stencilFuncSeparate(gl.FRONT, gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
  gl.stencilOpSeparate(gl.FRONT, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.REPLACE);
  gl.stencilMaskSeparate(gl.FRONT, 0xFF);
  gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);//error line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the WebGL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.10)

> ### 6.10 Stencil Separate Mask and Reference Value
>
> In the WebGL API it is illegal to specify a different mask or reference value for front facing and back facing triangles in stencil operations. A call to `drawArrays` or `drawElements` will generate an `INVALID_OPERATION` error if:
>
> - `STENCIL_WRITEMASK != STENCIL_BACK_WRITEMASK` (as specified by `stencilMaskSeparate` for the mask parameter associated with the `FRONT` and `BACK` values of face, respectively)
> - `STENCIL_VALUE_MASK != STENCIL_BACK_VALUE_MASK` (as specified by `stencilFuncSeparate` for the mask parameter associated with the `FRONT` and `BACK` values of face, respectively)
> - `STENCIL_REF != STENCIL_BACK_REF` (as specified by `stencilFuncSeparate` for the ref parameter associated with the `FRONT` and `BACK` values of face, respectively)

I'm going to guess [it's a DirectX limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074(v=vs.85).aspx) that had to be added so WebGL could be run in DirectX